# How to pass value of ComboBox in userform to macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass a value selected by user to be displayed in MsgBox. I write the following code but its display nothing.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    SelectedCity = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    DistSystem
End Sub

Sub DistSystem()
    MsgBox (SelctedCity)
End Sub
```

Comment: You also have a typo: `SelctedCity` should be `SelectedCity`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare Selectedcity as a public OUTSIDE of the Sub

```
Public SelectedCity as String

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    SelectedCity = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Call DistSystem
End Sub

Sub DistSystem()
    MsgBox (SelectedCity)
End Sub
```

Obviously place DistSystem in a module!

Answer (score 0):

Second procedure cannot read variable because of wrong scope.
You have to declare SelectedCity variable as global:

```
Global SelectedCity

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

SelectedCity = Me.ComboBox1.Value
DistSystem

End Sub

Sub DistSystem()

MsgBox (SelctedCity)

End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid globals whenever possible. Pass the value as an argument instead. -1

Comment: I make the changes and still display nothing

Comment: @DougGlancy don't tell people to avoid using things and not explain why. I use globals & publics all the time an never experience any issues

Comment: @LiamBee, some links: http://books.google.com/books?id=VnegO0pMYlIC&pg=PA58 http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?474662-How-dangerous-are-the-Global-Variables
http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=401865
http://www.codematic.net/excel-development/excel-vba/best-practice/coupling.htm
http://books.google.com/books?id=kesLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT218#v=onepage&q&f=false
https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/avoid-global-variables-environment-variables-and-singletons
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad
http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/c++.rules/chap7.html

Comment: @DougGlancy most of them are saying globals and publics are "bad" because you "might forget you've used them elsewhere"... That's what comments are for. **PERSONALLY** I like using them because it keeps things structured for **ME**. I define all of my Public Variables in one module and simply address them when needed anywhere in my code. And that works for **ME** and many other people too. However, if **YOU** want to do it your way, then that's ok too. Don't downvote other peoples perfectly acceptable answers because **YOU** wouldn't do it that way...

Comment: It's actually not about you and me. The purpose of SO is to give the best answer possible for the original poster, and for the people who arrive here looking for help. You argue that Excel/VBA experts are wrong about this widely-accepted best practice, but people who come here should know that your view is in the minority. I'm sorry it feels personal.

Comment: @DougGlancy actually I'm not arguing your wrong, I simply states that you didn't need to downvote because "Best Practice" wasnt followed, when infact, the method works fine for what the OP was trying to achieve. Some people don't want to be experts, they just want their application to run. Also, you should reference people in comments or they don't see them...

Answer (score 0):

There are times when you can't pass it in an argument, but you can pass it here.

```
Option Explicit 'forces to declare all variables

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
call DistSystem (Me.ComboBox1.Value)
'same as (  without call, and ()  ) :
' DistSystem Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Sub DistSystem(byval selectedCity$) 'same as: byval SelectedCity as string
MsgBox SelectedCity
End Sub
```

This works even if `DistSystem` is in a different module.